# Django automatic Logout and and after login it stays on same page

Tags: django, python-3.8

I am new to Django and using Django 3.0.2. Sometimes Django automatically logout and when I try to log in on my website then it stays on the login page but creates a session(I mean, I can see all the buttons which a user will see after login in header and footer). I am not experiencing this issue when I am manually logging out and logging in.

Please help if someone else is also experiencing the same issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Staying on the login page might have to do with your {{next}} value that redirects after a login. In your settings.py you need to set a LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  = '/'  (for me "/" is my index, I don't know what it is for you. I am assuming you are using the django built-in auth

Comment: Also, this question is poorly written (I can't even tell what the problem(s) are) and you don't provide any code. Can you specify what the issue is and post urls.py, views.py and maybe also some code from your templates

Comment: Hi @amchugh89: Please check my code below:                                                                                                               
**urls.py:**    url(r'^login$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True),namee='login'),
 url(r'^index_login', views.index_login, name='index_login'),

Comment: **setting.py:** LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index_login'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

Comment: I think it might be because namee='login'   should have only one e in name

Comment: **view.py:**@login_required
def index_login(request):
    # this view is created solely for the purpose of being able to log the login information through logToDb
    ut.logToDb(database, messages=['Successful login.'], user=request.user)
    ut.log_info('Successful login by ' + str(request.user) + '.')
    context = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'mainapp/index.html', context)

Comment: @amchugh89: it was typo while writing the code.Please check original code: url(r'^login$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),

Comment: **index.html:** {% extends 'mainapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<h3>Databases</h3>

<br/><br/>

<div class="fluid-container">    
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-vspace" type="button" href="plc/index">Inventory</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

{% endblock %}

Comment: @amchugh89: I am facing this problem only if Django logout automatically. But if I logout and login then I am not having issue so It is really tricky for me to generate the exact scenario.

Comment: did you read my comment namee should be name, also, to post code - do not do it in the comments, do it in the body of your original post using markup

Comment: @amchugh89: When I was pasting code by mistake I added e with the name. Actual code is as below:  url(r'^login$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login')

Comment: If anyone has any answer please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Today , again I had the same issue. I checked Django logs when I tried to log in I got "304 redirection" "GET /login?next=/plc/analysis_plc HTTP/1.1" 200 3975
"GET /login?next=/plc/analysis_plc HTTP/1.1" 200 3975
"GET /static/mainapp/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"GET /static/mainapp/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
"POST /login?next=/plc/analysis_plc HTTP/1.1" 302 0
"POST /login?next=/plc/analysis_plc HTTP/1.1" 302 0

Answer (score 0):

You can copy this - of course you need to change 'quizapp' to your app name

also, you need to make the correct template directories and add 'templates' to the TEMPLATES_DIRS in your settings

All of the following is my implementation of django default authorization which is outlined here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/

**MAIN SITE urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('quizapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**templates/registration/login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

{% if next %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
    please login with an account that has access.</p>
    {% else %}
    <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

**templates/base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AIDEN QUIZ</title>

    <style>

    </style>


</head>

<body>

    <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="{% url 'index' %}">aidenquiz.com</a>
          </li>
            <li>
         <a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next=/">Logout</a>  <!--  ?next=/ -->
          </li>
        </ul>
<span>
<a href="{% url 'quizzes' %}">Quizzes</a>
    <a href="{% url 'leaderboard' %}">Leaderboard</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com">Instagram</a>
</span>
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

  </body>
   <script>
{% block js %}

{% endblock %}

</script>

</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  = '/'
```

**views.py (in quizapp)**

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'quizapp/index.html', context)
```